# How to open camera with flash mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am developing a simple app in which i need to make my camera flash mode to be on continuously not only when capturing image. And the mode of operation should be camera not video recording. Is it possible ? If so than how. Please help me with some code

Comment: This link might have help you.

[How to access camera flash][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233100/how-to-access-camera-flash-with-xcode-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 8):

You can use the below method to toggle camera flash on and off.

```
- (void)toggleFlashlight
{
  AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

  if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff)
  {
    // Create an AV session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Create device input and add to current session
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create video output and add to current session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Start session configuration
    [session beginConfiguration];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

    // Set torch to on
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [session commitConfiguration];

    // Start the session
    [session startRunning];

    // Keep the session around
    [self setAVSession:session];

    [output release];
  }
  else
  {
    [AVSession stopRunning];
    [AVSession release], 
    AVSession = nil;
  }
}
```

You can also use the following method along with the display of camera,

```
- (void) toggleFlashlight {

// check if flashlight available
Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) 
        {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

        }
        else 
        {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];

        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
} 
}
```

[Source](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/camera/flashlight-application-using-the-iphone-led.html)

Comment: Be sure to check that the device has torch capability ;-) 
`BOOL deviceHasFlash = ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]);`

Comment: @atxe, That's true. That should be checked. But since he was planning to use for flash mode, I am assuming that, that is already checked.

Comment: this about code will work in video mode. I need to open flash light in camera mode not in video mode.

Comment: Can you try with the second option in answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Use this for Swift 4**

```
func toggleFlash() {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        else {return}

    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.torchMode == AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.on {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
                    //AVCaptureDevice.TorchModeAVCaptureDevice.TorchMode.off
            } else {
                do {
                    try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```